# React Native: How do I style NavigationExperimental's NavigationCardStack and NavigationHeader?

Tags: javascript, ios, css, react-native, reactjs

I am trying to change the background color of `NavigationExperimental`'s `NavigationCardStack` by: `style={{backgroundColor:'white'}}` but it does not work.

Is there a way around it? Or is it not possible?

Also, how can I hide the `NavigationHeader`'s 1px hairline? I tried doing `shadowHidden={true}` but it is not provided unfortunately.

Answer (score 0):

Your style prop is correct. But where are you applying it? You should apply this prop to *NavigationHeader*.

```
  <NavigationHeader
    style={{backgroundColor:'blue'}}
    ...
```

You are probably rendering the *NavigationHeader* in a separate function, maybe named renderHeader(). This function is passed as a prop to *NavigationCardStack*

```
    <NavigationCardStack
      onNavigateBack={this.props.onNavigateBack}
      renderHeader={this.renderHeader}
      ...
```

**edit:** answer to the question about the hairline:

```
    style={{backgroundColor:'blue', borderBottomWidth: 0}}
```

Here is the RN code for the hairline style, as you can see it's platform dependent:

```
    borderBottomWidth: Platform.OS === 'ios' ? StyleSheet.hairlineWidth : 0,
```